# Python tkinker label formatting

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I have a Python\Tkinter Label formatting question.

I have a simple main window with a Label that has its `textvariable` bound to a `DoubleVar()`
I want to display the value in the `DoubleVar()` as a US dollar amount, 
as in "$ 123.45"

How can I have the Label display the value the way I want?

I know I could change the textvariable to a `StringVar()` but then I have lost the precision of the `DoubleVar()`. I need it for other calculations in the app.

I have also tried sub-classing the Label class but couldn't figure out what method to override when the textvariable value is accessed.

How do I tell a Label how I want a number formatted?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. At least, not automatically. You can use a separate label just for the "$", or manually format the string for the label.

Comment: Yes, I can take the "$" out but then you still end up with floating point formatting problems as in 123.452349234

Comment: @user3298265: you have complete control over the formatting of a floating point number.

Comment: How and were? The Label will only display the value in the DoubleVar()  This is what I am trying to do.  Format the number for display.

Comment: Don't use a DoubleVar, just format the number using normal python formatting, and reconfigure the widget.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()

## str() temporarily changes the type of the variable to a string*
label = tk.Label(text=("$"+str(Doublevar()))
label.pack()

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: try explaining your answer to the OP.

Answer (score -1):

You could create a variable equal to "$" concatenated with the desired value converted into string, then display that string variable rather than the double variable itself. For example:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()


class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.textVariable = DoubleVar()
        self.stringTextVariable = "$" + str(self.textVariable)
        self.myLable = Label(master, text=self.stringTextVariable).pack()

variable = MyClass(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Overwriting the value of `self.textVariable` will result in `self.myLabel` displaying the new value when the program is ran again.

If you need to use the double value elsewhere in the program, just use the `self.textVariable` variable (which isn't displayed in the GUI) instead of the displayed `self.stringTextVariable`.

Comment: This doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Well what I think this code does is it makes a function within a class that takes a double variable (such as 123.45), converts it to a strings, adds a '$' in front of it, then packs that string into a label. Replace `DoubleVar()` in line 5 with 123.45 and run the code and tell me if something different happens.

Comment: `str(self.textvariable)` doesn't return the floating point value as a string. Also, the point of using a textvariable is to be able to change the value and the label automatically updates. Your code won't do that.